# Regex for password with minimum 6 characters length

Tags: c#

I need a regex to validate password with below conditions

1. At least 6 characters long
2. Should contain at least 1 letter
3. Should contain at least 1 number
4. If the password contains special characters, that should be allowed,  **but  special character is not mandatory**.

Comment: As muxh as I'd like it to be, this is not a code writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: I do not recommend using Regex for this purpose, as it'll be difficult (or less efficient) for you to understand what exactly is wrong with the user's password when it doesn't follow the password's requirements.

Comment: Seems easier to just loop over password and check individual chars in this case.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Please see [ask] and [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dontask)

Answer (score 4):

You can make separate patterns to validate the password:

```
var hasNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
var hasLetter = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]+");
var hasMinimum6Chars = new Regex(@".{6,}");
```

If special char it does not have to be so you dont need to check it.

```
var isValidated = hasNumber.IsMatch(input) && hasLetter.IsMatch(input) && hasMinimum6Chars.IsMatch(input);
```

Comment: Hi , i did try the below regex 
@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$";  but it returned false match if there were any special character